# Unable to find type when running powershell -command to bookmark rows of data in notepad++

Tags: powershell, notepad++

I have a PowerShell script which I intend to use to open specific csv files in Notepad++ then Search   ->   Bookmark rows based on one of the columns [Location] = 22102 and copy all bookmarked rows to a new sheet.

I'm still at the beginning of this process and have been search for a way for PowerShell to:

1. Open the csv files in Notepad++
2. Bookmark rows where the Location column = 22102
3. Then, open the Search tab in the ribbon to "Copy Bookmarked Lines"
4. Paste bookmarked lines into a new sheet

I'm able to open the required csv files with the following command:

```
$file = "C:\Files\Timings.csv"
$notepad = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

# Open the file in Notepad++
Start-Process notepad++ $file

# Wait for Notepad++ to open and become active
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

# Find the rows with Location 22102 and bookmark them
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Notepad++")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^f")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("Location: 22102")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F2}")

# Open the search option to cut the bookmarked rows
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^f")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F2}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^k")
```

However I'm struggling to get the ribbon opened to copy the bookmarked lines.

I keep getting the error "Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]," for all the VB commands, is there anyway I can fix this / define the VisualBasic SendKeys so I can use the properly?

Thanks

Comment: Use Select-String and the find lines with -Pattern.  Even better to use Import-CSV and read into table, then search the table.  There is no reason to use Notepad++.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm resigned to using Notepad++ at the moment. I will try both the Select-String & Import-CSV options you've suggested. Thanks

Comment: Call `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` to load the windows forms assembly

Comment: Add following to top of module :  using assembly System.Windows.Forms