# Unable to copy bookmarked lines to clipboard / new page when running powershell -command to bookmark rows of data in notepad++

Tags: powershell, notepad++, sendkeys

I have a PowerShell script which I intend to use to open specific csv files in Notepad++ then Search -> Bookmark rows based on one of the columns [Location] = 22102 and copy all bookmarked rows to a new sheet.

I'm still at the beginning of this process and have been searching for a way for PowerShell to:

1. Open the csv files in Notepad++
2. Bookmark rows where the Location column = 22102
3. Then, open the Search tab in the ribbon to "Copy Bookmarked Lines"
4. Paste bookmarked lines into a new sheet

I'm able to do steps 1&2 and I'm trying the introduction of ("^9") as a shortcut to copy bookmarked lines but I'm still struggling with step 3 copying bookmarked lines and 4 paste these into a new sheet. Can anyone help with this?

Code:

```
 $file = "C:\Files\Timings.csv"
 $notepad = "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

 # Open the file in Notepad++
 Start-Process notepad++ $file

 # Wait for Notepad++ to open and become active
 Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

 Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

 # Find the rows with Location 22102 and bookmark them
 Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
 [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Notepad++")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^f")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("22102")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^m")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ADD}")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
 
 # Get the bookmarked lines and copy them to the clipboard
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^9")
```

Once I get the bookmarked lines copied I hope to open a new notepad++ file and paste all them in the new notepad++ document:

```
 # Open a new Notepad++ document and paste the bookmarked lines
 Start-Process notepad++
 [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Notepad++")
 Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^n")
 [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^v")

 # Output bookmarked lines to a new CSV file
 $outputFile = $file -replace "\.csv$", "-modified.csv"
 $bookmarkedLines | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Encoding UTF8
```

Example of the data I'm working with:

```
Timing Event Sequence,Date,Operator,Operator Name,Operator Full Name,Operator Holding Company,Operator Type,Operator Franchised,TSC,TSC Description,TSC PfPI Flag,T Schedule Type,T ID,Location,Timing Event,Planned WTT Time,Actual,WTT Lateness,Delay
"0001","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","01100","Originate","09:08","09:08","0","2"
"1002","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:50","","","2"
"2003","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:51","","","2"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find type when running powershell -command to bookmark rows of data in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75606627/unable-to-find-type-when-running-powershell-command-to-bookmark-rows-of-data-in)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that through notepad++ ?

To create a new csv file that will contain only lines with value '22102' in the 'Location' column, it's as easy as:

```
$file    = "C:\Files\Timings.csv"
$outFile = $file -replace '\.csv$', '-modified.csv'
Import-Csv -Path $file -Encoding UTF8 | 
Where-Object { $_.Location -eq '22012' } |   # filter the data on column Location
Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

<sup>Without specifying some other character, the Import/Export-Csv cmdlets assume a **comma** as field delimiter.

If in your file you use a different character, add `-Delimiter <yourChar>` to these cmdlets</sup>

---

Using your Example

First of all, as commented, you need to surround your headers in the file with `"` quotes because they contain spaces.
When fixed, your example will look like this:

```
"Timing Event Sequence","Date","Operator","Operator Name","Operator Full Name","Operator Holding Company","Operator Type","Operator Franchised","TSC","TSC Description","TSC PfPI Flag","T Schedule Type","T ID","Location","Timing Event","Planned WTT Time","Actual","WTT Lateness","Delay"
"0001","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","01100","Originate","09:08","09:08","0","2"
"1002","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:50","","","2"
"2003","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:51","","","2"
```

Also, in your question you say you need to filter the data where column 'Location' equals `'22102'`, but looking at the example you gave you actually need to look for value `'22012'`..
(I have now changed that value in the code)

Running the above code would create a new csv file containing:

```
"Timing Event Sequence","Date","Operator","Operator Name","Operator Full Name","Operator Holding Company","Operator Type","Operator Franchised","TSC","TSC Description","TSC PfPI Flag","T Schedule Type","T ID","Location","Timing Event","Planned WTT Time","Actual","WTT Lateness","Delay"
"1002","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:50","","","2"
"2003","02/03/2023","HA","Manufacturing","Manufacturing","Ab CO.","C","FRANCHISED","9003","Gotham","Y","LTP","L27","22012","Pass","09:51","","","2"
```

Comment: Still getting an empty document opening up when I try this answer. [Side note] is there an easier way to read .csv files, filter for location, bookmark all rows with e.g. location 22102, cut them from original and paste them into a new .csv file?

Comment: @JimJanes So, what separator character (delimiter) does your csv file use? Please provide an example of thet (sanitized) file. Open it in notepad(++), copy the top 3 or 4 lines and paste that in your question as formatted text

Comment: @JimJanes I have added an example to show you the code works as intended. If as you say you get an empty file, that means 1) the delimiter character in your file is NOT the comma and you need to specify that with parameter `-Delimiter`, or 2) your inputfile has no headers, in which case you can specify them by supplying a string array on the Import-Csv cmdlet using the `-Header` parameter

Comment: I've updated my question to include some of the data I'm working with. I'm resigned to using Notepad++ in this circumstance given the nature of the current architecture however I'm open to suggestion for this. I'm still quite new with this language and I am struggling to apply your suggested parameter

Comment: @JimJanes Your headers need quotes, just like the data

Comment: Yeah, like Theo said, your headers for each column must also have quotes.

Comment: @JimJanes Please see the update of my answer. Not only do you need to fix your input csv file by quoting the headers, but also you want to look for value `22012`, NOT `22102`